# strtok, char**, and memory

Tags: c++, bash, strtok

So I'm working on my own **really awesome shell(rash)**, but I'm having a bit of tricky business when I'm tokenizing the strings.

It seems like somehow, even though the function ends (nothing more on the stack) there's still a bit of leftover for from the previous call.

Here's my code:

```
int  breakitup (std::string hamma){
    char cstr2[1024];
    char*  pch;
    char* bargv[1024];
    bargv[0] = (char*)"";
    strcpy(cstr2, hamma.c_str());

    //===DEBUGGER PRINT==vv
    std::cerr << "Cstring passed in: ";
    puts(cstr2);
    //===================^^

    pch = strtok(cstr2, " ");

    for( int p = 0; pch != NULL; p++){
        bargv[p] = pch;
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    //===DEBUGGER PRINT==vv
    std::cerr <<"Resulting tokens:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::cerr << "*";
        puts(bargv[i]);
    }
    std::cerr << "=======================\n\n";
    //===================^^

    return fcall(bargv);
}
```

I've been starting with commands with 2 arguments (to avoid the obvious segfault in the debugger).

For this example, I enter:

```
ls -a
echo hello!
ls
exit (quit rash)
```

---

```
$ ./bin/rshell
rash$ ls -a

===DEBUGGER PRINT===
%ls -a: 0
1ls -a
Cstring passed in: ls -a
Resulting tokens:
*ls
*-a
=======================

.  ..  bin  famcho  fanny  .git  ls  ls.o  lsy  Makefile  .notrshell  obj  readme  README.md  rshell.cpp  shelly  supershell
rash$ echo hello!

===DEBUGGER PRINT===
%echo hello!: 0
1echo hello!
Cstring passed in: echo hello!
Resulting tokens:
*echo
*hello!
=======================

hello!
rash$ ls

===DEBUGGER PRINT===
%ls: 0
1ls
Cstring passed in: ls
Resulting tokens:
*ls
*hello!
=======================

ls: cannot access hello!: No such file or directory
rash$ exit

===DEBUGGER PRINT===
%exit: 0
1exit
Cstring passed in: exit
Resulting tokens:
*exit
*hello!
=======================

Ar revoir!
```

I asked this question under a broad title because I can only imagine its a memory issue with `char**`, or `strtok()`. But hey, you'll probably know better than me!

Comment: Why are you using `strtok` in the first place? The io streams tokenize on spaces by default.

Comment: `char cstr2[1024]; strcpy(cstr2, hamma.c_str());` Can you guarantee that this string is always less than 1023 character? This is unsafe and could hurt the stack if the compiler places `cstr2` there.

Comment: You should decide whether you're writing C or C++. There are a quite a few adjectives for this kind of hybrid, but "awesome" isn't one, unless you're using the mediaeval meaning of "inspiring terror".

Comment: i don't understand why you are copying the contents of a `std::string` to a C-Style string.  Are you aware of all the helpful methods for `std::string`, like `find_first_of`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your code.  Most can be solved by using what C++ has to offer.

You started to use `std::string`, but then went into "C mode" and took away all of the safety and ease-of-use of doing things the C++ way.

So a basic rewrite of your code using C++ constructs would look something like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//...
int fcall(std::vector<std::string>& bargv)
{
   //...  you fill this in here
   return 0;
}
//...
//...
int  breakitup (const std::string& hamma)
{
    std::vector<std::string> bargv;
    std::istringstream strm(hamma);
    std::string s;
    while (strm >> s)
    {
        bargv.push_back(s);
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    return fcall(bargv); 
}

int main()
{
    breakitup("This is   a test  string");
}
```

Live Example: http://ideone.com/zZAgFd

The usage of `std::istringstream` and `std::vector` removes the need for `strtok` and manual memory management.  Also there is no issue of buffer overflow as there are no hard-coded limits.  The input string can have 1 word or 10,000 words separated by spaces, the function will still work.